# Need to Export the application which i created in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have created a program using the netbeans, I need to export the complete run file. so that I can login from the desktop rather than opening the netbeans IDE and running the loginUI jframe. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your application `*.jar` file under `dist` folder, which you can find under your project folder.

Then, you can execute this jar using

```
java -jar <jar_file_name>.jar
```

While executing above command, you need to provide `classpath` and required arguments, if any.